# Spring Boot - Custom JsonDeserializer is ignored

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, deserialization, spring-webflux, json-deserialization

I am trying to apply a custom Jackson deserializer (class "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer") to a bean from a third-party library that requires custom deserialization. My custom deserializer is written in Kotlin:

```
@JsonComponent
class CustomDeserializer: JsonDeserializer<ThirdPartyBean> {

    constructor(): super() {
        println("CustomDeserializer registered")
    }

    override fun deserialize(parser: JsonParser?, context: DeserializationContext?): ThirdPartyBean? {
        // Custom deserialization
    }

    override fun handledType(): Class<*> {
        return ThirdPartyBean::class.java
    }
}
```

I have tried to do all of the following (and in fact all combinations thereof):

1. Use the class as-is: I can see that the deserializer is picked up - I can see the "CustomSerializer registered" being printed.
2. Annotate the field that uses the ThirdPartyBean with the custom deserializer (see below)
3. Explicitly register the Deserializer with the ApplicationContext (see below)

Ad 2:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer::class)
fun getThirdPartyBean(): ThirdPartyBean = thirdPartyBean
```

Ad 3:

```
@Bean
fun jacksonBuilder(): Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder {
    return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
        .deserializers(CustomDeserializer())
}
```

Regardless of what I have tried, I always get this client-side error when attempting to serialize a bean that - among other properties - contains a property of type "ThirdPartyBean":

```
    org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.example.ThirdPartyBean]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.ThirdPartyBean` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

Spring Boot version is 2.3.1. I am at wits end on how to solve this, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this on my own. However I'm pretty sure there must/should be a much simpler solution, so I'm happy to hear any suggestions. I solved the problem by manually registering a Jackson module that contains my CustomDeserializer in the WebClient setup:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebFlux
class MyApplication: WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var objectMapper: ObjectMapper

    @Bean
    fun webClient(): WebClient {
        val customDeserializerModule = SimpleModule()

        customDeserializerModule.addDeserializer(ThirdPartyBean::class.java, CustomDeserializer())
        objectMapper.registerModule(customDeserializerModule)

        return WebClient
            .builder()
            .codecs { it.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(Jackson2JsonDecoder(objectMapper)) }
            .build()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but my answer here will be in Java as I've just solved the same issue for myself

The problem is how you're registering the module. If you look at the `JsonComponentModule` class you'll see that it uses the following

```
@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() {
  registerJsonComponents();
}

public void registerJsonComponents() {
  BeanFactory beanFactory = this.beanFactory;
  while (beanFactory != null) {
    if (beanFactory instanceof ListableBeanFactory listableBeanFactory) {
      addJsonBeans(listableBeanFactory);
    }
    beanFactory = (beanFactory instanceof HierarchicalBeanFactory hierarchicalBeanFactory)
      ? hierarchicalBeanFactory.getParentBeanFactory() : null;
  }
}
```

This is when it creates the deserializers. This so happens to occur after the bean is configured, so creating a `new JsonComponentModule()` breaks this. It never wires in the beans.

In order to make this work you there's two options. If Spring is using Jackson auto configuration then you need to autowire in the already configured `JsonComponentModule` bean provided by spring e.g.

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(JsonComponentModule jsonComponentModule){
  return new ObjectMapper()
    .registerModule(jsonComponentModule);
}
```

If not, then you will first need to create the `JsonComponentModule` bean. e.g.

```
@Bean
public JsonComponentModule jsonComponentModule() {
  return new JsonComponentModule();
}
```

And then autowire that into your object mapper creation.